# Imports Unrecognized By IntelliJ when Getting A Project From GitHub

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I've faced this problem quite a lot lately but I didn't care in the past and decided to rewrite the whole project I'm getting from GitHub but now when the project is enormous I can't do this anymore.

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image: Picture]

As you see the classes are already in their places but the import still failing I don't know why. I checked my SDK and it's already added so anyone have an idea why this happening?

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a Maven project, open the Maven tab and click `Reimport all dependencies` button.

Another solution is to use the Terminal, just run `mvn clean install` command.

Comment: To be honest I just deleted the project and reinstalled it from GitHub so I can't try this solution anymore. However, I think it works because I remember that one time this happened to me and I re-downloaded all the dependencies from Maven and it worked so I assume this answer to be right.